# Duvidas Array Python

Tags: python

possuo um script que pega todos os Serviços do Windows e filtros somente os que têm MSSQL e depois pego semente o nome dos serviços conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém preciso pegar os valores do Array e comparar com um valor em especifico (é aqui é ta meu problema) quando print o array e o local que eu quero (ws[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPvu0.png)) ele me da esse retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é: O pq isso ocorrendo sendo que estou pegando a 1 casa do array?

Segue o código

```
import psutil, re
import numpy as np 
#with open('C:\Zabbix\Install\Texto.txt', 'w+') as arq:
#    arq.writelines (str(list(psutil.win_service_iter())))
s =str(list(psutil.win_service_iter()))
s = s.split()
x = 0
y = 0
j = 0
ws = []
for item in s: 
    if 'MSSQL' in s[x]:
        v = str(s[x])
        v = v.replace('(', '')
        v = v.replace(')', '')
        v = v.split("'")
        ws = str(list(filter(lambda w: w.startswith('MSSQL'), v)))
        print(ws[1])

    x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema está nesta linha:

```
ws = str(list(filter(lambda w: w.startswith('MSSQL'), v)))
```

O `str()` ali está convertendo o resultado em uma string! Então quando você acessa `ws[1]` está pegando o segundo caracter dessa string (o primeiro seria `ws[0]`).

Veja também que mais acima em

```
s =str(list(psutil.win_service_iter()))
```

e em

```
v = str(s[x])
```

Você também está convertendo a lista em string! Isso faz com que você tenha que dar `split`, remover parênteses com `.replace(), etc - tudo isso não seria necessário se você simplesmente usasse o objeto lista diretamente - os parênteses só são gerados porque você está pedindo o python para fazer uma representação do seu objeto em forma de string.

Em python é melhor você trabalhar com as estruturas de dados do jeito que são, ao invés de converter tudo em string. Eu sugiro remover todos esses `str()` - essa função só deve ser usada quando você realmente precisa de uma string.

Comment: Entendi porém, quando eu tiro eu não consigo capturar os valores por ser uma classe de da LIB PSUTIL... isso que me "quebrou", então meio que sou obrigado a fazer isso

Comment: @WallaceBrunoGentil classes dessa lib podem ter seus valores capturados sim... Tente inspecionar a classe, use o comando `dir()` ou `help()`, procure exemplos - converter para string é a forma errada de fazer e vai te trazer problemas sempre.